# Linearizing maximization problem around $t=0$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, linearization

I have a maximization problem $\max f(x;t)$ given $g_i(x;t)=0$ where $t$ is a parameter (time)(exogenous). Also I know the solution to the problem for $t=0$. Can I in any way linearize (taylor expansion) near $t=0$ and use Lagrange Multipliers method to solve for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ because it will be a linear system of equations?
In the actual problem $x$ is a vector but you can think of it as scalar in order to answer this question. When I naively linearize all equations around $t=0$  ($\max \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \dot{x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ subject to $ \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x} \dot{x}+\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial t}=0$),the problem gets trivial and nothing can be solved.

Comment: You are much better off using a professionally developed nonlinear optimization solver. Such a solver may use quadratic or linear approximations in various places, and in controlled and adaptive ways. if you do it yourself, you're likely to end up with a piece of junk algorithm, which might happen to work o.k. on some problems,and be a disaster on others. Or it may be a disaster on all problems.

Comment: @mark-l-stone can you suggest some of these software?

Comment: First tell us what the functions f and g are,and if there are ant other constraints. Unless f is jointly concave in x and t, and g is linear (affine) in x and t, which apparently is not the case, this is a non-convex optimization problem. If you want to find the global maximum (i.e., the true maximum subject to the constraints), as opposed to a local maximum which may not be a global maximum, you will need to use a global optimization solver. The choice of which one depends on additional details of f and g, as well as computing environment.

Comment: Warning, there are a lot of solvers such as genetic algorithms and simulated annealing, which are called global optimization solvers, but really aren't. Appallingly, the MATLAB Global Optimization Toolbox doesn't have a single actual global optimization solver - just a bunch of heuristic sstuff, which is at best a crapshoot, and whose results cant be trusted.